# Python pandas: Group by 1 column, remove groups if values in 2 other columns meet criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
group    day         result
1         -1           yes
1         1            no
1         22           yes
1         56           no
2         -1           no
2         1            yes
2         22           no
2         56           yes
3         -1           no
3         1            no
3         22           yes
3         56           yes
```

In Python, how do I group by "group" and then filter out `day <= 1 and result == yes`. To be filtered out the group has to meet both criteria (no result on Day -1 or Day 1).

Expected df

```
group    day         result
3         -1           no
3         1            no
3         22           yes
3         56           yes
```

I've started with this:

```
remove_df = df.groupby(['group']).filter(lambda x: (x['day'] != 1).any())
```

I'm not really sure how to proced from here.

Comment: _then filter out day <= 1 and result == yes_, is it `day <= 1 or result == yes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there.
You need to apply a filter which checks each group, this is what is passed to the lambda x.
This is where it checks if day is <= 1 and result == yes.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'day': [-1, 1, 22, 56, -1, 1, 22, 56, -1, 1, 22, 56],
    'result': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
filtered_df = df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: ~((x['day'] <= 1) & (x['result'] == 'yes')).any())

display(filtered_df)

   group  day result
8      3   -1     no
9      3    1     no
10     3   22    yes
11     3   56    yes
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficient than `filter`, you could also use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and boolean arithmetic:

```
out = df[(~(df['day'].isin([-1,1])
           &df['result'].eq('yes')
            )
          .groupby(df['group'])
          .transform('max')
         )]
```

Output:

```
    group  day result
8       3   -1     no
9       3    1     no
10      3   22    yes
11      3   56    yes
```

Intermediates:

```
    group  day result   -1/1    yes      &    max      ~
0       1   -1    yes   True   True   True   True  False
1       1    1     no   True  False  False   True  False
2       1   22    yes  False   True  False   True  False
3       1   56     no  False  False  False   True  False
4       2   -1     no   True  False  False   True  False
5       2    1    yes   True   True   True   True  False
6       2   22     no  False  False  False   True  False
7       2   56    yes  False   True  False   True  False
8       3   -1     no   True  False  False  False   True
9       3    1     no   True  False  False  False   True
10      3   22    yes  False   True  False  False   True
11      3   56    yes  False   True  False  False   True
```

Comment: Yep this is more efficient as it works directly with the dataframe without the overhead of the groupby and filter operations.